# Parsing a very hectic space delimited file

Tags: php, mysql, import, export, csv

I'm trying to help my dad out -- he gave me an export from a scheduling application at his work. We are trying to see if we can import it into a mysql database so he/co-workers can collaborate online with it.

I've tried a number of different methods but none seem to work right -- and this is not my area of specialties.

Export can be seen here: http://roikingon.com/export.txt

Any help / advice on how to go about parsing this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks !!

Comment: Advice... well, you should know data format of that export. Also, addresses are space-separated, and there is no tabs between columns - it seems it lacks some info to parse automatically.

Comment: My guess: it's fixed width and the first 3 characters are the record type. Every record type has the same format (that means every line with the record type 4 has the same two columns, record type 17.1 has only one column but it seems to start a new "route block").

Comment: poor form for not including your data inline. Now the link is dead, so its impossible to contextualize your question. Or use pastebin et al... just sayin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made an attempt to write a (somewhat dynamic) fixed-with-column parser. Take a look: http://codepad.org/oAiKD0e7 (it's too long for SO, but it's mostly just "data").

What I've noticed

- Text-Data is left aligned with padding on the right like `"hello___"` (`_` = space)
- Numerical data is right aligned with padding on the left `"___42"`

If you want to use my code there's yet stuff to do:

- The record types 12.x have variable column count (after some static columns), you'd have to implement another "handler" for it
- Some of my width's are most probably wrong. I think there is a system (like numbers are 4 characters long and text 8 characters long, with some variations for special cases). Someone with domain knowledge and more than one sample file could figure out the columns.
- Getting the raw-data out is only the first step, you have to map the raw-data to some useful model and write that model to the database.

Comment: Ha! i'm actually doing the very same thing. I did it slightly different tho. I used a switch rather then a large array with a function that returns an array of the data per line.

good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

With that file structure you're basically in need of reverse engineering a proprietary format.  Yes, it is space delimited but the format does not follow any kind of standard like CSV, YAML etc. It is completely proprietary with what seems to be a header and separate section with headers of their own.

I think your best bet is to try and see if there's some other type of export that can be done such as Excel or XML and working from there. If there isn't then see if there's an html output of some kind that can be screen scraped, and pasted into Excel and seeing what you get.

Due to everything I mentioned above it will be VERY difficult to massage the file in its current form into something that can be sensibly imported into a database. (Note that from the file structure a number of tables would be needed.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use split with a regular expression (zero or more spaces).

I will try and let you know.

There doesnt seem to be a structure with you data.

```
$data = "12.1  0    1144713      751  17  Y   8  517  526  537  542  550  556  561  567                                     17 ";

$arr = preg_split("/ +/", $data);
print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [0] => 12.1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1144713
    [3] => 751
    [4] => 17
    [5] => Y
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 517
    [8] => 526
    [9] => 537
    [10] => 542
    [11] => 550
    [12] => 556
    [13] => 561
    [14] => 567
    [15] => 17
    [16] =>
)
```

Try this `preg_split("/ +/", $data);` which splits the line by zero or more spaces, then you will have a nice array, that you can process. But looking at your data, there is no structure, so you will have to know which array element corresponds to what data.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey - this was my first thought.. And started to implement but then realized this is considered "column delimited" which means there may be null records and doing this would skip over the those records. I found a PDF that somewhat explained what was going on and in it... it included a field length. using that field length i am able to use substr($row, $column-position, $field-length)

Comment: like i said good luck. it s very hard to parse this kinda data.

Answer (score 1):

Open it with excel and save it as comma-delimited. Treat consecutive delimiters as one, or not. Then resave it  with excel as a csv, which will be comma-separated and easier to import to mysql.

EDIT:
The guy who says to use preg_split on "[ +]" is giving you essentially the same answer as I just did above.

The question is what to do after that, then.

Have you determined yet how many "row types" there are? Once you've determined that and defined their characteristics it will be a lot easier to write some code to go through it.

If you save it in csv, you can use the PHP fgetcsv function and related functions. For each row, you would check it's type and perform operations depending on the type.

I noticed that your data rows could possibly be divided on whether or not the first column's data contains a "." so here's an example of how you might loop through the file.

while($row = fgetcsv($file_handle)) {
  if(strpos($row[0],'.') === false) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}

"do something" would be something like "CREATE TABLE `table_$row[0]`" or "INSERT INTO `table`" etc.

Ok, and here's some more observation:

Your file is really like multiple files glued together. It contains multiple formats. Notice all the rows starting with "4" next have a 4-letter company abbreviation followed by full company name. One of them is "caco". If you search for "caco", you find it in multiple "tables" within the file.

I also notice "smuwtfa" (days of the week) sprinkled around.

Use clues like that to determine the logic of how to treat each row.

Comment: If you take a closer look at the file you'll see that this is not a simple matter of converting to a CSV. The data contained therein is much more complex than that. It will/would require reverse engineering, parsing and then import into a number of different tables.

Comment: It's hard to even tell what the data structure is. It would be more useful if you actually posted a summary of what structures you need to decode.

Comment: I seemed to have been able to do this using substr and following a format per section